# django-allauth: rearrange form fields (change order)

Tags: django, forms, django-allauth

I am trying to use django-allauth for user registrations. I have this form

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('gender', 'country', 'city', 'birth_date', 'has_accepted_tos')
```

and as per instructions I have set in my settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "userprofile.forms.UserProfileForm"
```

The problem is that when the form is rendered my custom form asking for gender, country etc is rendered on top and then the standard User fields that ask for username, email and password. Something in this order:

- gender
- country
- city
- birth_date
- has_accepted_tos
- username
- email
- password1
- password2

  I would like to display the fields in this order
- username
- email
- password1
- password2
- gender
- country
- etc

Comment: Please create a separate question for the second issue.. and remove it here.

Comment: OK I removed the second question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide the `field_order` attribute:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('gender', 'country', 'city', 'birth_date', 'has_accepted_tos')
        field_order = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'gender', 'country']
```

However, a better practice would be to use the template file to render the form exactly as you want to.

Quoting the project author:

> (...) Then again, I would not put too much weight on what allauth has
>   to offer out of the box display/design wise. All of this is just for
>   reference, the idea is that you create a proper design & form layout
>   in your templates.

References:

[1] https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py

[2] https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/269

Comment: Thank you. At the end I went route number two and rendered the template exactly as I wanted. I just didn't know I could do that.

Comment: Hi, from reading the code in [1], ```field_order``` was not to be placed on the "Meta" but rather on the class itself?